# About Church encoded lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, church-encoding

Various optimisation problems, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101329/efficient-bitstreams-in-haskell), led to Church encoded lists as a way to enable stream fusion, i.e the compiler's elimination of intermediate results (e.g. lists). Here's the definition that was used successfully in the optimisation problem:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

-- A list encoded as a strict left fold.
newtype ListL a = ListL {build :: forall b. (b -> a -> b) -> b -> b}
```

Here's how I look at Church-somethings: Instead of asking what an 'something' *is*, ask what it *can do* for you. In the case of lists the answer is: Lists can be folded over. In order to fold, I need an 'update' function of type `b->a->b` and a starting value of type `b`. Then I will give you back the result of the fold, which is of type `b`. Hence the definition of `ListL`. Here are a few basic operations on `ListL`:

```
mapL :: (a -> a') -> ListL a -> ListL a'
mapL f l = ListL (\f' b' -> build l (\b a -> f' b (f a)) b')

instance Functor ListL where fmap = mapL

fromList :: [a] -> ListL a
fromList l = ListL (\c z -> foldl' c z l)

toList :: ListL a -> [a]
toList l = build l snoc [] where snoc xs x = xs ++ [x]

nullL :: ListL a -> Bool
nullL l = build l (\_ _->False) True
```

Here's more:

```
filterL :: (a->Bool) -> ListL a -> ListL a
filterL p l = ListL (\f b->build l (\b' a'->if p a' then f b' a' else b') b)

iterUntil :: (a->Bool) -> a -> (a->a) -> ListL a
iterUntil p a f = ListL (\g b-> snd $ until (p.fst) (\(a',b')->(f a', g b' a')) (a,b))
```

`iterUntil` iterates a function `a->a`, starting with some value of type `a`, until the predicate `a->bool` is fulfilled. A function like Prelude's [`iterate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) isn't possible - at least I don't know how to define it, it would have to be some kind of recursion.

Continuing with examples, `length` and `sum` are just exercises in choosing the right 'update' function and starting value in a `foldl`:

```
lengthL :: ListL a -> Int
lengthL l = build l (\b _ -> b+1) 0

sumL :: Num a => ListL a -> a
sumL l = build l (+) 0
```

Now, let's try `headL`:

```
headL :: ListL a -> a
headL l = build l (\_ a->a) _   -- this does not compile!
```

No matter what starting `b` is provided, the first `a` should be returned. `build l` needs a `b`, but we don't have one. This is a weird one: Basically we want to tell the compiler: You don't need the `b`, trust me... A `headL' :: ListL a -> ListL a`, on the other hand, is easy to construct. An `error "empty list!"` in place of the hole `_` doesn't work because it always gets called - laziness doesn't seem to take care of this. So, with `headL` I'm stuck. Therefore here is

**Question 1: How is `headL` implemented?**

The second issue appears when trying to implement the equivalent of [`repeatM :: Monad m => m a -> m [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yjtools-0.9.18/docs/Control-Monad-Tools.html#v:repeatM). As with `iterUntil`,  predicate `a->Bool` is needed to stop the iteration:

```
iterUntilM :: Monad m => (a->Bool) -> m a -> m (ListL a)
```

The purpose is clear: Repeat a monadic action `m a` until `a->Bool` is satisfied. The idea is, of course, to fold this `ListL a` right away and achieve stream fusion (list fusion). For example:

```
import System.Random (randomIO)

main :: IO ()
main = do
     rs <- iterUntilM (>42::Int) randomIO
     print $ lengthL rs
```

The example is rather contrived, it prints the number of draws it took until the first number >42 was found. In a more realistic setting the monad `m` is, for example, an [`ST s`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html) monad that wraps some FFI. The point is: This should run efficiently. I'm thoroughly stuck with this one. How do I entangle the `(>>=) :: m a -> (a->m b) -> m b` with `build` to get a `m (ListL a)`? I.e. this is

**Question 2: How is `iterUntilM` implemented?**

Other than being a good learning exercise, is this actually a good idea?

Comment: `headL l = fromMaybe (error "headL: empty list") (build l (\z x -> z <|> Just x) Nothing)`?

Comment: yes that does the `headL` job indeed! (What does this `<|>` do, exactly?)

Comment: this version I understand: `headL l = fromMaybe (error "headL: empty list") (build l (\z x -> if isJust z then z else Just x) Nothing)`

Answer (score 5):

In general, when you remove assumptions about a type, the function you write will not only be more general (in terms of what types it can use), it will also be more *specific* about what exactly it's doing. That's what's happening with the church-encoding allowing fusion: when lists are represented as

```
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

There are countless ways to use those in a function, only one of them being `foldr`. However, when you have:

```
newtype List a = { runList :: forall b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> b }
```

The *only* way to use that type is through `foldr`. This is what lets you do the optimisations we know and love. Stream fusion is just one of them, by the way: you also get *O(1)* append, for instance.

Your type is more constrained still: it tells us that the underlying list can't be (meaningfully) infinite.

There's another constrained representation of lists that shifts the focus:

```
data List a = forall b. List b (b -> Maybe (a, b))
```

Where the church-encoded list is a consumer, this is a *producer*. It says nothing about how the list can be consumed, but an awful lot about how it can be made.

So we've seen that we get a lot from these constrained representations, what do we lose? `tail` is a good example. For the producer:

```
tail (List x f) = case f x of
  Just (_,xs) -> List xs f
```

And for the consumer:

```
tail xs =
    List (\c n ->
        runList xs 
            (\h t g -> g h (t c)) 
            (const n) 
            (const id))
```

The consumer's implementation is *O(n)*, whereas the producer's is obviously *O(1)*.

Both of these types can allow for fusion, but some functions can be more efficiently implemented in one than the other. GHC happened to choose the former representation as its basis for fusion, but there's nothing fundamental that makes that choice superior: most functions Haskellers were using just seemed to work better in the `foldr/build` pattern of fusion than the other one. In [other places](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/haskell-beats-C.pdf), the unfolding pattern is used.

That preamble out of the way, there are two questions we need to ask:

- Do these functions (`head` and `iterUntilM`) work efficiently in only the `foldr` representation (like append), or in the `unfoldr` representation (like `tail`), or both (like `map`)?
- Is the strict left-fold encoding the right choice for these? Is it too constrained (ie do we need `foldr`?), or can it be constrained even more?

`head` can be implemented on `foldr`-encoded lists pretty easily:

```
head xs = runList xs const (error "head: empty list")
```

On `foldl'`-lists, it's a little more complicated:

```
head xs =
    fromMaybe
        (error "head: empty list")
        (build xs (\xs x -> maybe (Just x) Just xs) Nothing)
```

You'll notice that this function (like `tail` on `foldr`-lists) is *O(n)*. It also doesn't work for infinite lists. This is a good indication that `foldl'` isn't the right choice for fusing `head`.

Now, for `iterUntilM`, we see a case where (I don't think) even *fusion* is possible. Because the `m` ends up on the outside, you have to run all of the effects in the list (materialising it).

For a good overview of this area, check out [this](https://jyp.github.io/posts/controlled-fusion.html) blog post.

Comment: For some problems (e.g. the one I [quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101329/efficient-bitstreams-in-haskell) at the top, this foldl-type Church list offers the best performance. It seems to me that this is just like the discussion about `foldr` vs. `foldl'`. Each has its purpose. What really interests me is `iterUntilM`. All the effects in the `ListL` will have to be run, that's the purpose of the list (being more of a `foldl'`-type thing). Efficiency aside (let's experiment!), how is `iterUntilM` done? I'm still stuck here.

Comment: `iterUntilM` can't be implemented without converting to a list (either implicitly or explicitly). Because every effect has to be pulled to the outside, they all have to be run, meaning the internal list *will* have to be created. In other words, if you wrote `fmap fromList . repeatM` it would be equivalent. Also—`foldr` and `foldl'` aren't different in the same way that `foldr` and `unfoldr` are: `foldl'` can be implemented using `foldr` (it's how it's done in the prelude), but not so with `foldr` and `unfoldr` (without materialising the intermediate list).